# WP Query: How to get posts from a specific author OR those with a specific meta value

Tags: wordpress

I would like to retrieve all those posts whose author (post table field) is a given one OR those which has a given meta value (postmeda table field).

If "author" was a meta value, I know I could use a meta_query to achieve it. The thing here is that it is not... so I think I cannot use the "author" field within a meta_query and use the "relation" key.

I'm looking for something like:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => array('post'),
    'orderby'    => 'ASC',
    'order'      => 'date',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'relation'    => 'AND',
            array(
                'field'   => 'author',
                'value'   => $author_id,
                'compare' => '==',
            ),
            array(
                'key'     => '_meta_field_name',
                'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
            ),
        ),
        array(
            'relation'    => 'AND',
            array(
                'key'     => '_meta_field_name',
                'compare' => 'EXISTS',
            ),
            array(
                'key'     => '_meta_field_name',
                'value'   => $meta_field_value,
                'compare' => '==',
            ),
        ),
    ),
);

$data = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Any suggestion on how to achieve that using WP_Query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might like to try an approach like this one instead. The idea is to query the two conditions you want to search for, then merge the two queries into one finished product.

```
//Get posts with the author you're looking for
$args1 = array(
    'author_name' => 'testuser', //or 'author' => $author_id or something else
     );
$data1 = get_posts( $args1 );

//Get posts with the meta data you're looking for
$args2 = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'meta_field_name',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'meta_field_name',
            'value'   => $meta_field_value,
            'compare' => '==',
        ),
    ),
);
$data2 = get_posts( $args2 );

//Merge both arrays
$allData = array_merge( $data1, $data2 );

//Get just the IDs of all the posts found, while also dropping any duplicates
$postIDs = array_unique( wp_list_pluck( $allData, 'ID' ) );

//Do a new query with these IDs to get a properly sorted array of post objects
$args3 = array(
    'post__in' => $postIDs,
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    );
$finalAnswer = get_posts( $args3 ); //This is your array of post objects. Ta-Da!
```

Comment: Thanks @Myles! That works like a charm! I thought it could have been done with one single query, though. May be using a custom query? Would it be better in terms of performance? Could you assist on how that custom query should look like? Many thanks again!

Comment: I don't think it can be done in one query, no. I tried looking into that but as you've described in your question, it doesn't seem like it'll take author OR meta. The query only returns what it finds with all given conditions to be true. Using two queries is the only way I could come up with. But the performance implications should be minimal